# How to hide some members of an interface

Tags: c#, collections, icollection

I would like to create a custom collection that implements `ICollection`.

But I would like not to expose some memebers of `ICollection` like `Clear` method.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Your best way IMO is creating another interface with those "hidden" methods.

Comment: Why not just use `ReadOnlyCollection`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can implement the interface explicitly and have the implementation hidden:

```
public class UrClass : ICollection
{
    void ICollection.Clear() { ... }
}
```

The user can't call `urClassInstance.Clear()` directly, but they can call `((ICollection)urClassInstance).Clear()` indirectly like this.

Comment: Thanks, in this code:  Dictionary<int, int> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();
            var ic = ((ICollection)dict);  Why I can't access `IsReadOnly` on ic ? It is a member of ICollection

Comment: @Mark Lachowski: use `ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>> dict = new Dictionary<int, int>();` or `var ic = ((ICollection<KeyValuePair<int, int>>)dict)`. The non-generic `ICollection` does NOT implement the `IsReadOnly` property.

Comment: That is exactly how ReadOnlyCollection works. It is recommended to subclass that one in stead of creating your own. Still +1 though.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Interface members are always public... otherwise, the class would fail to implement the interface.  That's why access modifiers are not allowed in interface member declarations.

There are two ways of declaring members that satisfy the interface requirements: implicitly and explicitly.

Implicitly, any public member with a matching signature will be used:

```
public interface IGuess
{
    void Guess();
}

public class Guy : IGuess
{
    public void Guess() {}
}
```

This is a "normal" member of the class and will be reflected on instances of the type.

You can also, as @Jaroslav points out, explicitly designate members as satisfying an interface definition:

```
public class Guy : IGuess
{
    void IGuess.Guess() {}
}
```

In this case, the member will not appear unless the instance is cast to the interface type.  It is still public.

Comment: `Dictionary` implements `ICollection` but `IsReadOnly` property from `ICollection` is not visible on dictionary, how can it be?

Comment: @Mark Lachowski: see my answer.

Comment: @Mark Lachowski: Jaroslav Jandeks is a good explanation of part of the answer, the other part is a design pattern called Composition. When you compose a structure it does not inherit it's parts from an interface or class, it uses the interface and/or class to build it's parts. In many cases, C# does not hide an interface member, it is usually not inheriting that interface member because it is using the Composition design pattern to build or compose the parts it needs from the interface or class. This makes it possible to include only what you want and need and never anything you don't.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into the [ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx). You could make a private innerclass and let it implement `ICollection`. Then Make a method that returns `ReadOnlyCollection` by calling `AsReadOnly` on that object. 
Or just subclass it if that fits your design. It is preferred to subclass this collection rather than try to create your own implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it empty or launch a NotImplementedException

Comment: `NotSupportedException` makes more sense since I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide those members from your own collection's interface, you can define them explicitly.

```
void ICollection.Clear() {
    // ...
}
```

Explicitly defined members are only available if the instance is used through that interface.

```
YourCollection col1 = new YourCollection();
col1.Clear(); // this is not allowed if clear is defined explicitly

ICollection col2 = new YourCollection();
col2.Clear(); // this will work because col2 is ICollection
```

Answer (score 0):

What makes you so sure that you really need to implement `ICollection`? If you don't want some methods from this interface, don't use it, declare a new interface with methods that you want. The whole point of using `ICollection` is to make other objects think that they can do with your object whatever they can do with any other collection.

Comment: Take a look at the ReadOnlyCollection class: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx.  It implements `ICollection`, but uses explicit interface implementation to "hide" the members that modify the collection. And those methods throw `NotSupportedException`. Still, it makes sense to implement `ICollection` because it's a familiar interface that people know how to use. They just can't modify it.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather suggest you to consider "Composition" over "Inheritance" here.

That gives you more control over what all to expose to the outer world, with added advantage of dynamic binding with the actual collection.