# Why doesn't Dictionary<TKey, TValue> not have a Add method that takes a KeyValuePair object?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, collections, interface

According to the .NET API, the class `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is inherited from `ICollection<T>`, where `T` is `KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>`. How does the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` class hide some of the methods it inherits from `ICollection<T>`?

For example:

`ICollection<T>` has the method `ICollection.Add(T item)`
but when you use a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` object it doesn't have that method. You can only use `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(TKey key, TValue value)`. There is no `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue> kvp)` method.

Anyone know why? How are those methods hidden?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is done by implementing the Interface explicitly and making this implementation private/protected... see

- [How to hide some members of an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284750/how-to-hide-some-members-of-an-interface/5284799#5284799)
- http://www.iridescence.no/post/HidingInterfaceMembers.aspx

You could always cast the `Dictionary` to `ICollection` and then call `Add` - though I wouldn't do this because I don't know whether it would work...

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question precisely. In the past I never implemented an interface explicitly so I didn't realize that was the effect of explicit implementation.

Comment: the effect is not "automatic" but only if you change from public to private/protected for example by ommitting any access modifier...

Answer (score 4):

They're "hidden" use [explicit interface implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173157.aspx). So you can use:

```
ICollection<KeyValuePair<Foo, Bar>> collection = dictionary;
collection.Add(...);
```

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673027.aspx) that *should* work... although usually it would be simply to use an alternative approach.

Comment: Thanks Jon, you always have good answers. I was unaware of the explicit interface implementation. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Because the Dictionary has an explicit implementation of `ICollection.Add`. You'd need to cast it to `ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` before you could use it.

You can see the implementation on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc673027.aspx)

```
void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(
    KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair
)
```

Answer (score 1):

For reference, the `Dictionary<>` code for the explicitly implemented `ICollection<>.Add()` method is:

```
void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair)
{
    this.Add(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
}
```

You should be fine to use it, since it's just doing what you would likely have done yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If `Dictionary` directly exposed an `Add(KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>)` overload, that would suggest that if one had a `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` (e.g. received when one was enumerating another dictionary) it would be better to pass it to such a method than to read out the `Key` and `Value` properties and pass them separately.  In fact, the reverse is true: passing the whole structure to an `Add` method which then had to decompose it and pass its members to a discrete-parameter overload would be less efficient than decomposing the structure into its members and passing them separately.

Note that if the `Dictionary` stored things internally in an array of a structure type which had `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` as a field (not property), then code like:

```
for var item in Dict1
{
  Dict2.Add(item);
}
```

could be more efficient than

```
for var item in Dict1
{
  Dict2.Add(item.Key, Item.Value);
}
```

but since `Dictionary` will decompose any passed-in `KeyValuePair`, there's no reason to encourage the former style of code.