# If you want to hide the interface member with a better name, you SHOULD consider explicitly implementing the interface member

Tags: c#, .net

How to understand this sentence:

•   If you want to hide the interface member with a better name, you SHOULD consider explicitly implementing the interface member

This is C# guideline, but I can't understand it well.

Comment: take a look at [how-to-implement-an-interface-without-making-members-public-using-explicit-interface-implementation](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnwpowell/2008/06/13/how-to-implement-an-interface-without-making-members-public-using-explicit-interface-implementation/)

Comment: see this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284750/how-to-hide-some-members-of-an-interface